# could not find property on root project gradle for custom task

Tags: java, build, gradle, build.gradle

I have written a custom task `copyDocs` to copy the build output to some other directory and have given this task in the `dependsOn` as following:

```
task doit(dependsOn: ['clean', 'build', 'copyDocs'])
build.mustRunAfter clean
copyDocs.mustRunAfter build
....
....
task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
     from 'build/libs'
     into 'build'
 }
```

Above is the custom task `doit` that has to execute `clean`, `build` and `copyDocs` in the order defined using `mustRunAfter`. But it gives an error during execution.

```
During execution (i.e. cmd>gradle doit), I am getting the following error:

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find property 'copyDocs' on root project 'gradle'.
BUILD FAILED
```

Please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Please try defining `task copyDocs` before writing `copyDocs.mustRunAfter build`.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error since there is no defined task called `copyDocs` when `copyDocs.mustRunAfter` executed.
You should put `copyDocs` task definition before `copyDocs.mustRunAfter build` statement.